# Google ML Engine: Submit a training job via REST API

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to start a training job via a REST API request using the Census example project from Googles github. I'm able to submit a job, but it always fails as I'm unable to state where the training and evaluation (testing) files are kept, and the documentation is really lacking on this - it just states `args[]`. When I check the logs in Google ML, the following errors appear:

`task.py: error: the following arguments are required: --train-files, --eval-files`

`The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 2.`

This is my formulated REST request:

```
{
    "jobId": "training_12",
    "trainingInput": {
        "scaleTier": "BASIC",
        "packageUris": ["gs://MY_BUCKET/census.tar.gz"],
        "pythonModule": "trainer.task",
        "args": ["--train_files gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.data.csv", "--eval_files gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.test.csv"],
        "region": "europe-west1",
        "jobDir": "gs://MY_BUCKET/",
        "runtimeVersion": "1.4",
        "pythonVersion": "3.5"
    }
}
```

Under the `args` I've tried many different ways of stating where the train and eval files are, but I have been unable to get it to work. Just for clarification, I have to use the REST API for this use case - not the CLI.

Thanks

-- Update --

I've tried to have the args as `--train-files` and `--eval-files`, this still does not work.

-- Update 2 --
I've been able to solve this problem by formulating the args as:

```
"args": [
          "--train-files", 
          "gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.data.csv", 
          "--eval-files", 
          "gs://MY_BUCKET/adult.test.csv", 
          "--train-steps",
          "100",
          "--eval-steps",
          "10"],
```

Now, I'm getting a new error and the logs don't seem to give any more information: `"The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1."`

The logs have actually done some training, and I suspect this is something related to the saving of the job, but I'm unsure.

Comment: I would advise you to keep different issues in different StackOverflow questions, given that the two issues you reported seem unrelated and you already found the solution to your original issue. Note that you can [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept your answer 48h after the question creation, so this is a good practice in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, there is no need to share bucket names or any other project-related information in public questions, so please use placeholders like `MY_BUCKET` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that. Changed my question. Also I agree dsesto, I'm going to make a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you already found the solution to your issue with `args` when submitting a Training Job in Google Cloud ML Engine. However, let me share with you some documentation pages where you will find all the required information regarding this topic.

In this first page about [formatting configuration parameters](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-jobs#formatting_your_configuration_parameters) (under the *Python* tab), you can see that the `args` field is populated like:

```
'args': ['--arg1', 'value1', '--arg2', 'value2'],
```

Therefore, the correct approach to define `args` is writing them as *key-value* pairs as independent strings.

Additionally, this other page containing [general information about Training jobs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-overview#params), explains that the training service accepts arguments as a list of strings with the format:

```
['--my_first_arg', 'first_arg_value', '--my_second_arg', 'second_arg_value']
```

That is the reason why the last formatting you shared (below) is the correct one:

```
"args": [
          "--train-files", 
          "gs://BUCKET/FILE", 
          "--eval-files", 
          "gs://BUCKET/FILE_2", 
          "--train-steps",
          "100",
          "--eval-steps",
          "10"]
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. I released the args were key pair values as stack very nicely showed me a similar post where someone has correctly configured the args.

Now, my current issue is related to the saving of the model I suspect. I'll update my OP.

Comment: I am glad that helped! Feel free to [accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And please, do not change the content of the question. Instead, create a new one with the new issue you found, providing all the necessary information, with as much details as possible.